# Target sdk 30 and All File Access permission

Tags: android, sdk, android-permissions, google-play-console, unhandled-promise-rejection

My app is rejected due to All file access permission but our app needs it without that it won't work out. we are not able to upload app with target sdk 30 or 31 and All File Access permission?

Comment: You better tell why your app needs 'it'.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play notice
This section provides a notice for developers who publish apps on Google Play.

To limit broad access to shared storage, the Google Play store has updated its policy to evaluate apps that target Android 11 (API level 30) or higher and request "All files access" through the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. This policy takes effect in May 2021.

When your app targets Android 11 or higher, and it declares the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, Android Studio shows the lint warning that appears in figure 1. This warning reminds you that "the Google Play store has a policy that limits usage of" the permission.

Figure 1. Lint warning in Android Studio that reminds you about the Google Play policy regarding the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
You should request the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission only when your app cannot effectively make use of the more privacy-friendly APIs, such as Storage Access Framework or the Media Store API. Additionally, the app's usage of the permission must fall within permitted uses, and must be directly tied to the core functionality of the app. If your app includes a use case that's similar to the following examples, it's likely to be allowed to request the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission: